# FirebaseFunctionsException INTERNAL but no stacktrace in cloud console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Flutter application in production that is using Firebase cloud function for the backend and sometimes it throws some `FirebaseFunctionsException INTERNAL` errors for one particular function but without much information on the client side.

The weird thing is that I don't even have information on the console side, if I look at the logs I don't see any call to the function... I tried to put `minInstance` to the cloud function but I still have the error.

The particularity of the function where I have the error is that it's called by ~40 users at the same time, some have an error, some do not...
Is someone know how I can find out what is going on?

edit: Here is the front-end stacktrace I got. No trace on the cloud function logs.

```
FirebaseFunctionsException

[firebase_functions/internal] INTERNAL

#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:296)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:23)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: Without the code of your Cloud Function and the front-end code used to call it we can hardly help you.

Comment: Even if it's a problem in my front-end or in my cloud function, I should have an error somewhere to tell me what is the problem. I've updated my response with the stack trace I got from the front-end, it's unusable. And nothing on the cloud function logs.

Comment: `decodeEnvelope` would suggest that a client is trying to call the function without using the client's version of `functions().httpsCallable("yourFunction").call(data)`

Comment: That's what I'm doing, most of the time the call is working, but sometimes it's failing with this error

Comment: I really think that there is something broken with the firebase cloud function when many users calls a function that doesn't have an active instance

Comment: I am also getting this error intermittently. Please let us know if you find a resolution. Might be worth reporting it as an issue against the cloud_functions package on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Try add a timeout to the call to the cloud function. Example:

```
final HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('yourFunctionName');
final HttpsCallableResult result = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
  'param1': 'value1',
  'param2': 'value2',
}).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));
print(result.data);
```

Explanation: timeout is a method of Future class, so you can use it on the result of the call to the cloud function. If the cloud function takes more than 10 seconds to return, the timeout will throw an exception. You can then catch that exception and handle it.

Comment: I'm already calling `initializeApp` at the start of the function file

Comment: Thanks for your response, but even if I catch the error it doesn't fix my problem because it should not throw an exception... I've contacted Google to report the problem, I should at least have a detailed message error somewhere

Comment: good luck. any news let us know